# how to omit mysql rows that match another table when neither is unique

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one that holds potential items, the other holds completed items.

The potential item table currently contains the records that have also been added to the completed items table.  I want to remove (either by deleting or selecting new results) the already completed items from the list of potential items.

In both tables, items may appear multiple times, and I only want to remove the number of items that are completed, not all that match.

The real data set is more larger of course, but here are samples.

Potential items:

```
mysql> select * from stack;
+----------+------+------+
| stack_id | type | name |
+----------+------+------+
|        3 | a    | aa   |
|        4 | b    | bb   |
|        5 | c    | cc   |
|        6 | d    | dd   |
|        7 | a    | aa   |
|        8 | b    | bb   |
+----------+------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Completed items

```
mysql> select * from temp;
+----------+------+------+
| item_id | type | name |
+----------+------+------+
|        1 | a    | aa   |
|        2 | b    | bb   |
|        6 | b    | bb   |
+----------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The IDs between tables do not correlate, so they should be ignored as far as finding matches.

I want to omit 1 instance of a/aa and 2 of b/bb since those have been completed and exist in the other table.

when I try this:

`mysql> select stack.* from stack where (type,name) not in (select type,name from temp);`

I get this:

```
+----------+------+------+
| stack_id | type | name |
+----------+------+------+
|        5 | c    | cc   |
|        6 | d    | dd   |
+----------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

But this omitted both instances of type="a" and name="aa" and I want to only omit one of them (since it only exists once in the completed items table)

How do I get this?

```
+----------+------+------+
| stack_id | type | name |
+----------+------+------+
|        5 | c    | cc   |
|        6 | d    | dd   |
|        7 | a    | aa   |
+----------+------+------+
```

I don't care which instance of a/aa is deleted (whether id=7 or id=3)

The best I've been able to come up with is to use PHP rather than MySQL to loop through each record in temp and delete with a LIMIT 1 from stack.

But I'd rather not have to run code for this, I'd like to do it in queries, it works better that way in my workflow

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not entirly clear. Are you looking for a query to include or exclude items from one list if they appear on another list?

Comment: I'd like either a query to delete the duplicate rows, or to select the non duplicate rows.  My current solution is to use php to generate a bunch of "delete from .... limit 1" queries.

Comment: Are you looking for the first occurance of ['a', 'aa'] in the stack list then you can use `select min(stack_id), type, name from stack group by type, name` or `select min(stack_id), s.type, s.name from stack s inner join temp using (type, name) group by s.type, s.name` so combine the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`stack` (
  `stack_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `type` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`stack_id`));

CREATE TABLE `test`.`temp` (
  `item_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `type` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`));
```

and than something like this:

```
select
    min(stack_id), type, name
from stack _s 
inner join 
(
    select min(item_id) item_id, type, name
    from temp
    group by type, name
) _t using(type, name)
group by _s.type, _s.name
```

will give you only one the first item in temp:

| stack_id | type | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | a | aa |
| 4 | b | bb |